# flutter upgrade starts but fails at some point

Tags: flutter, curl, dart

I run flutter upgrade. It starts downloading but fails at some point.
This is what happens...

```
rjey@MacBook-Pro ~ % flutter upgrade
Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine 5babba6c4d25fa237bbf755ab85c9a0c50b3c6ec...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  2  172M    2 4829k    0     0   319k      0  0:09:12  0:00:15  0:08:57  327k
curl: (18) transfer closed with 176023571 bytes remaining to read

Failed to retrieve the Dart SDK from: https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/flutter/5babba6c4d25fa237bbf755ab85c9a0c50b3c6ec/dart-sdk-darwin-x64.zip
If you're located in China, please see this page:
  https://flutter.dev/community/china
```

And my browser is downloading fine.

Comment: Do you use any proxies, VPNs or other network related things? (or have advised flutter  to do so?)

Comment: No, I don't use any proxies and VPN

Answer (score 0):

What flutter doctor says?

You could try to switch to "stable" channel and run upgrade again.

Comment: when I run any flutter command it starts to upgrade